# How to prevent macOS from inserting an NSVisualEffectView into an NSScrollView automatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview, nsvisualeffectview

I'm building a `NSView` hierarchy programmatically by putting a `NSStackView` into a `NSScroller`. I have done this before and my code is correct.

The view hierarchy is what I expect until the first time through the runloop (or display) where macOS Catalina (and I think Mojave) automatically insert a `NSVisualEffectView` into the view hierarchy. This is messing up my custom drawing no end..

The hierarchy that I create is

```
NSScrollView -> NSStackView -> stack subviews
```

this is "enriched" by the scroll view before the first display loop into:

```
NSScrollView -> NSClipView -> NSStackView -> stack subviews
```

and after the first display the NSVisualEffects View is added at the same level as the NSClipView:

```
NSScrollView -> NSClipView          -> NSStackView -> stack subviews
             -> NSVisualEffectsView
```

Is there a way to tell the scroll view that I don't want the visual effects view?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is similar to the [problem with NSPredicateEditor in a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345734/macos-dark-mode-ui-bugs-with-nspredicateeditor-in-a-sheet/60842764), but in that case Apple is *not* inserting the VEV and everything looks wrong as a result. My code there for adding it might be useful for removing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue when I try to recreate the spotlight window. The screenshot below shows a table view (enclosed in a scroll view) in a visual effect view:

[image]

In older version of macOS, the opaque background here is the background drawn on scroll view (or clip view), which we can simply remove it by setting a clear background color, or setting `drawBackground` to `false` as Lucas suggested.

However, due to the insertion of this visual effect view in newer version of macOS (Catalina, maybe?), this won't works:

[image]

It has an opaque content background material, and I don't find any APIs or documents related to this behavior.

---

**The Workaround**

What works for me is to hide the inserted visual effect view in my `NSScrollView` subclass:

```swift
class ScrollView: NSScrollView {
    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: NSView) {
        super.didAddSubview(subview)

        if subview is NSVisualEffectView {
            subview.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Update**

If you are using `NSTableView`, instead of the above "hack", it's preferred to set table view's style to be source list:

```swift
// for macOS 11 Big Sur
tableView.style = .sourceList

// for macOS 10.15 Catalina and older
tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .sourceList
```

When you do so, the system automatically configure the scroll view and table view for source list appearance (or sidebar). More specifically, scroll view doesn't insert visual effect view, and the table view's row view are semi-transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have to set `drawsBackground` to be `false`. So with a reference to NSScrollView, you'd call something like this after the view is loaded up or assign this value in the xib/storyboard file.

```swift
scrollView.drawsBackground = false
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add an `NSTableView` or `NSCollectionView` inside an `NSScrollView` its `drawsBackground` property is ignored and an `NSVisualEffects` view added unless you explicitly set `.backgroundColor = .clear` on table view and collectionview inside.

So for correct behavior:

```swift
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
scrollView.drawsBackground = false
```